# Vigor 2920 cannot reach linux LAN device from VPN or WAN after some time (timeout?)

Tags: linux, vpn, port-forwarding, routing, draytek

Setup:

- Gateway: Vigor 2920, Firmware: 3.3.6.1, 2 fiberlines, loadbalancing.
- I have 2 XEN Citrix server with virtual Debian (DomU) running on the LAN. (PROBLEM)
- Other devices running on the LAN: Windows PC, NAS etc. (Not having any problem)
- PPTP VPN (Remote dailin)
- Apache Webserver on Debian (DomU). Accessible from WAN through "Port Redirection)

The problem is that the servers have to do continious PING to the gateway; if not the connection will be lost both from WAN and from VPN.

It also works if the servers are accessed frequently from VPN or WAN, but it doesn't work if there has been no traffic for some time (some hours maybe).

The problem typically comes overnight, when there is no traffic.
Connection is working again as soon as the server send some PING messages to the gateway.

My guess is that Linux is rather quiet when its not used, and that Windows computers keep on yapping so that's why the problem is not seen with the Windows computers.

Any ideas how to solve this, other than making sure the Linux coputers have ongoing traffic, for example ping?

Answer (score 2):

Well basically this issue is sort of caused by the Atheros AR8316 switch that is used by the Vigor 2920, since it only supports one FID. The mac address of the LAN device you wish to connect to will age out from the switch's mac table in 5 minutes (unless it sends another packet to the Vigor) and you will not be able to connect to that device through the WAN interface due to VLAN configurations on the switch.

We have fixed this issue and I believe the 3.3.6.2 firmware will be released in a couple weeks.